# How to fetch field details of a dynamically selected object?

Tags: apex, visualforce, metadata

I want to create a Visualforce page to have dynamic picklist of objects in the org.
Once a user selects any value from the list, it will show the list of fields for that object in a table below with field details like:

- Field Label
- Field API Name
- Field Type
- Field Length
- Field Description

Comment: There is an app available in the AppExchange called [Schema Surfer](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wZM3EAM) that does what you describe.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm

Schema describe as described above will help you

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_schema.htm

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm

Use parallely the field describe to get Field Lenght label APi and other info